# Problem with database access using multithreading JDBC create/update/insert queries

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I have a multi-threaded Spring Boot application which inserts a vast amount of data into a MySQL.
When the application starts, a single thread is running to persist the "main" data. This works well.
After the "main" data is persisted, multiple threads are started to insert data into various sub-schemas (also MySQL), suing the data persisted by the "main" (a type of replication process with complex rules).

What I observe are strange SQL errors, which do not occur when I run the application single-threaded, so I am suspecting that multi-threading is causing the issue.

None of these seem to help. I am getting errors like:
- Bad SQL grammar (which is not the case, as I said, single threaded works)
- empty SQL statement (which is not possible)

I hope that anyone on this forum can shed some like on this

Things I have tried:
- making the DAO which I use to insert data into the sub-schema a prototype bean, so there is one distinct DAO per thread
- making the NamedParameterJDBCTemplate (used in the DAO) a prototype bean
- making the DataSource used by the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate a prototype bean

===>>> Configuration

```
// Target data source
@Bean(name = "targerDSProps")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "target.server")
public DataSourceProperties targetDSProps(){
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "targetDS")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "target.server.configuration")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public DataSource targetDS(){
    return targetDSProps().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}

@Bean(name = "targetNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate targetJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("targetDS") DataSource targetDS) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(targetDS);
}
```

===>>> The DAO

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Slf4j
public class TargetDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "targetNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedTargetJdbcTemplate;
```

None of these seem to help. I am getting errors like:
- Bad SQL grammar (which is not the case, as I said, single threaded works)
- empty SQL statement (which is not possible)

Comment: Is the data **really** persisted or are the threads started as part of the ongoing transaction for the main data. Which means you can have an issue until the data gets committed. Making things prototype scoped won't really help. Basically without seeing the code that you are running (how the things are stored and threaded) an answer is impossible to give.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was using an enum to dynamically build queries, forgetting that enums are static by nature. I replaced this by a map, it works now.